# Use a different colour for containers depending on the theme

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

I implemented a Dark Mode in my App with this Tutorial:

https://developer.school/flutter-dynamic-theming-with-provider/

Everything is working fine but i have a little Problem with a single Container.

I specified a specific color for it.

```
return Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
    vertical: 32.0,
    horizontal: 24.0,
  ),
  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
    bottom: 20.0,
  ),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color:  Color(0xFFD3D3D3),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
  ),
```

Now i need to change the Color of the Container depending on my current Theme.

Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would be of best practice to use a bool value to switch from Dark to Light Mode

then you can do this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThemeChanger with ChangeNotifier {
  bool isDark == false;

  void changeTheme() {
    isDark = !isDark;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

then call it like this

```
class MaterialAppWithTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
      theme: theme.isDark == false ? ThemeData.light() : ThemeData.dark(),
    );
  }
}
```

to change a Container style

```
class MaterialAppWithTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);

    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 32.0,
        horizontal: 24.0,
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: 20.0,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: theme.isDark == false ? Color(0xFFD3D3D3) : Colors.black,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light ?  Color(0xFFD3D3D3) : Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
  ),
```